# linear hashing: c++ implementation, rehashing issues

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, hashtable

I'm working on the C++ implementation of linear hashing..

In short the structure is organized in so called buckets (arrays) and each bucket can have its overflow bucket (that overflow can also have an overflow, etc.).

> In the code the overflow Bucket looks like this: bucket*
>   overflowBucket{nullptr}; //pointer to the overflow bucket and the
>   bucket itself is made with struct bucket{} --> each has its array of
>   elements of fixed size and pointer to overflow.

When element is to be inserted in the table it should be checked if it already exists, if not insert it. However if the bucket in which the element should be inserted, is full, the new overflow should be added, but before that the 'next-to-split'bucket is supposed to be rehashed using the new hash function..

Anyways my program so far does most of the things right, however when I insert a new element in a bucket whose overflow is already full, instead of creating a new overflow and **triggering rehash** of next to split bucket,

*it only creates the new overflow..*

The parts of code relevant for this are: 
The main function for inserting element:

```
void insertElementInTable(const key_type& key) {
     //compute the index of the bucket that the key should be inserted in
     size_type start_idx{hashIndex(key)};
     bool check = table[start_idx]->Full();
     if(check == true) { //if the bucket is full, then...
        //...rehash the nts bucket
        rehashNextToSplit();
     }

     //then compute index again and insert the element in the bucket finally
     size_type final_idx = hashIndex(key);
     table[final_idx]->insertElementInBucket(key);

     //then check if round needs to change and if yes then double the size of the table for future splits
     if((nextToSplit-1) == roundNum) {
         roundNum += 1;
         nextToSplit = 0;
         replaceOldTable(roundNum);
     }

     //increase the number of elements in the table
     overallElementCount += 1;

 }
```

Function full (where I think the problem might be, but I don't see it)

```
    bool Full() {
        size_type numBuckets{0}, numElements{0};
        bucket* helper = this;

        //counts all the elements in primary and all overflow buckets
        while(helper != nullptr) {
            numBuckets += 1;
            for(unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
                if(helper->Bucket[i].state == State::taken) {
                    numElements += 1;
                }
            }
            helper = helper->overflowBucket;
        }

        //set up real size and max size of bucket
        size_type real_sz = numElements*numBuckets;
        size_type max_sz = N*numBuckets;

        //if the real size matches the max size, bucket is full and return true
        return real_sz == max_sz;
    }
```

REHASH next to split function:

```
 void rehashNextToSplit() {
        //store the contents of nts bucket and its overflows in temporary vector
        //COPY ELEMENTS AND CLEAR BUCKET
        std::vector<value_type> vec;
        vec = table[nextToSplit]->contentCopyAndClear();

        //PROCEED WITH REHASHING
        //first increment nts
        nextToSplit += 1;
        //then insert again the values from the vector
        size_type sz = vec.size();

        for(unsigned i=0; i<sz; ++i) {
            size_type idx = hashIndex(vec.at(i));
            table[idx]->insertElementInBucket(vec.at(i));
        }

        //when done free the memory used by the help vector
        vec.clear(); 
        vec.shrink_to_fit();

    }
```

Content copy and clear function called by rehashing methid:

```
std::vector<value_type> contentCopyAndClear() {
        std::vector<value_type> vect;
        bucket* ptr = this;
        bool cond{true};

        while (cond == true) { //goes through all buckets and copies the values into the vector
            for(unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
                if(ptr->Bucket[i].state == State::taken) {
                    vect.push_back(ptr->Bucket[i].key); //copy element
                    ptr->Bucket[i].state = State::free; //free the elements
                }
            }
            if(ptr->overflowBucket == nullptr) { cond = false; }
            ptr = ptr->overflowBucket;
        }

        //reset ptr to first overflow
        ptr = this->overflowBucket;
        delete ptr;

        return vect;
    }
```

Hash function:

```
size_type hashIndex(const key_type& key) const {
    size_type idx = hasher{}(key) % (1<<roundNum);

    if(idx < nextToSplit) {
        size_type d{roundNum + 1};
        idx = hasher{}(key) % (1<<d);
    }

    return idx;
 }
```

And insertElementInBucket called also by rehash function:

```
void insertElementInBucket(const key_type& key) {
        bucket* next = this;

        while(true) {
            for(unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
                if(next->Bucket[i].state == State::free) {
                    next->Bucket[i].key = key;
                    next->Bucket[i].state = State::taken;
                    return;
                } else {
                    if(key_equal{}(next->Bucket[i].key, key)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(next->overflowBucket == nullptr) {
                next->overflowBucket = new bucket;
            }
            next = next->overflowBucket;
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code I won't paste here because of readability and simplicity of the post but you can see it under this link: https://pastebin.com/TtdN5tBU

And the problem summed up one more time:

After inserting number 17 in pic below, the number 4 from the first table should be rehashed (using 4 mod 2^3) to bucket no. 2

[image: [insert problem]]

And the numbers 3 and 55 in the picture below should be entered only once (after rehashing they should be deleted from the bucket no. 1

[image: [rehashing problem]]

I would be very very grateful for any tips, since I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days without 0 progress now..

Comment: It's hard to help without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The classic [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should help you, and stepping through in the debugger can also be useful.

Comment: There's not enough code here in the question for us to tell what's wrong with it.  In particular, the `rehashNextToSplit` function (and anything it calls) could be the culprit.  [Edit] your question to add this code.